# Split by capital letters, no abbreviations

Tags: php, string

I want to split my string by capital letters, but only if those aren't abbreviations.

Consider the following strings:

- ThisIsAText
- SOS

This first string should become `This Is A Text`, while the second should just remain `SOS`.

My approach was:

```
$old_str = "ThisIsAText";
$arr = explode ( '/(?=[A-Z])/', $old_str );
$new_str = implode ( " ", $arr );
```

Could this also be done with only 1 function?
Also, this doesn't consider abbreviations.

Comment: I dont think explode take regex expression...o.O

Comment: Have a look at [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use preg_replace like this:

```php
$result = trim(preg_replace("/(?<![\^A-Z])([A-Z])/", " $1", "ThisIsAText"));
```

This is adding a whitespace before every capital letter NOT preceeded by another capital letter.

Unfortunately this does not split "ThisIsAText" correctly, because the A is followed by a capital T.

So a better definition of what you consider an "abbreviation" would be helpful to provide a better solution.

Comment: When testing it with `SOS`, I get `SO S`.